# Tensor Backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, implementation

I tried to make simple neural network layers as the following, including forward and backward propagation. Here is my [reference](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/handouts/derivatives.pdf).

Firstly I assume an one layer FC:

$Y = X \cdot W + B$

X is input, which size is (N, D), N=batch-size, D=features; W is weight, which size is (D, M), D=features, M=next-layer features

then I stack it as two layer FC:

$Y_1 = X_1 \cdot W_1 + B_1$

$Y_2 = Y_1 \cdot W_2 + B_2$

Backpropagation:

Gradient w.r.t. $W_1$:

$\frac{\partial Y_2}{\partial W_1} = \frac{\partial Y_2}{\partial Y_1} \frac{\partial Y_1}{\partial W_1} = X_1^T \cdot W_2^T$ ( I move $w_2$ to the right side to follow the order in forward prop; also, I perform transpose to sum the features along batch axis.)

Gradient w.r.t. $W_2$:

$\frac{\partial Y_2}{\partial W_2} = Y_1^T$

The Problem:

I used the following snippet to verify above equations, but the results from Tensorflow are not the same as my assumption, specifically the gradients of $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Which part am I wrong?

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.executing_eagerly()
    tf_batch_x = tf.constant(x_batch_array)
    l1_tf_batch_weight = tf.Variable(l1_weight_array)
    l1_tf_batch_bias = tf.Variable(l1_bias_batch_array)
    l2_tf_batch_weight = tf.Variable(l2_weight_array)
    l2_tf_batch_bias = tf.Variable(l2_bias_batch_array)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tf_out = tf.matmul(
            tf_batch_x,
            l1_tf_batch_weight) + l1_tf_batch_bias

        #tf_out = tf.nn.relu(tf_out)
        
        tf_out = tf.matmul(
            tf_out,
            l2_tf_batch_weight) + l2_tf_batch_bias
        #tf_out = tf.nn.relu(tf_out)
    tf_grad = tape.gradient(tf_out, [l1_tf_batch_weight, l1_tf_batch_bias, l2_tf_batch_weight, l2_tf_batch_bias])
    print("tf_out", tf_out)
    print("tf_grad", tf_grad)
```